# Perforce Swarm, how to access outside of local network?

Tags: port, perforce, vsphere, swarm

I just deployed the Helix Evaluation on my vSphere environment. I can access Perforce just fine outside of my LAN with the help of port forwarding. However Swarm doesn't use ports such as 'perforce-server-ip/swarm/'. How can I access Swarm outside of my LAN so my global team mates can use it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Swarm is a web app, all you should need to forward is port 80 (same way you forwarded port 1666 for the Perforce server).